# Getting ClassNotFoundException in MongoPartition in Spark in cluster mode, in local mode, code runs fine. How to resolve?

Tags: mongodb, scala, maven, apache-spark, sbt

When I am running the scala code from Intellij in local mode, it works fine. However, when I am trying to run it in cluster mode, I am getting the following error.
I even tried creating a `jar` and used `Spark-Submit`, even then I am getting a separate error.

```
var connectionString = MongoDBCredentials.getConnectionString(view_name)
    spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").
    option("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoSinglePartitioner").
    option("uri", connectionString).
    load()
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoPartition

It looks like my MongoDB dependency is somehow not going over to executors. But how should I get it pushed to executors?

I am using the Spark cluster running in docker container.
Here is my code that I am using [Github](https://github.com/shantanugupta/spark-mongo-sqlserver-cluster-mode/blob/main/src/main/scala/com/sparkTutorial/input.scala)

After reading few articles, I tried including the following dependencies in my build.sbt as well but with no luck.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver" % "3.0.1" from "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/mongodb-driver-3.0.1.jar"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-core" % "3.8.1" from "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.8.1/mongodb-driver-core-3.8.1.jar"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "bson" % "3.8.1" from "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/3.8.1/bson-3.8.1.jar"
```

Also added mongodb connector in SparkSession

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).
      appName("Spark SQL basic example").
      config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1").
      config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").
      getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Can you share how your jar/zip is packaged?

Comment: Make sure you create a fat jar file with `mongo-spark-connector` jar or provide the jar file while running the `spark-submit`

Comment: Here is what I am trying for packaging jar
https://github.com/shantanugupta/spark-mongo-sqlserver-cluster-mode/blob/main/build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same issue using the mongodb assembly jar

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/3.0.1/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1-assembly.jar

In the spark conf:

```
.config("spark.jars", "mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1-assembly.jar")
```

Spark reading:

```
df = spark.read.format("mongo")\
        .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:password@host:port/database.collection?&authSource=admin&tls=true")\
        .load()
```